# HTTPでのOLYMPUS AIRの撮影について

Tags: olympus-camerakit

現在、通信仕様書を元に、MacBookAirからHTTPを使用してカメラの操作を試しています。

動作モード変更、電源OFF、状態の取得、レンズ操作等はできたのですが、写真の撮影が出来ない状態です。
写真の撮影には、撮影モードへの切り替えの他に何か必要な前提条件があるのでしょうか？

実行しようとしているコマンドは

```
exec_takemotion.cgi?com=newstarttake&point=0600x0200
```

で、レスポンスは

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
<errorcode>0xB000</errorcode>
<errormsg>WIFI_INTERNAL_ERROR</errormsg>
<dbgmsg>reserved</dbgmsg>
</response>
```

です(これしか出ないようですが…)。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

拝見しました。

撮影モード切り替え時に`switch_cameramode.cgi?mode=rec&lvqty=0640x0480`を指定していますでしょうか？

`exec_takemisc.cgi?com=startliveview&port=5555`でライブビュー転送開始していますでしょうか？

`exec_takemotion.cgi?com=newstarttake&point=0600x0200`で、AFポイント座標(600,200)を指定しているようですが、SDKドキュメントのカメラプロパティ[TOUCH_EFFECTIVE_AREA_UPPER_LEFT](https://opc.olympus-imaging.com/sdkdocs/data/PropertyList/property_list.html#property_27)、[TOUCH_EFFECTIVE_AREA_LOWER_RIGHT](https://opc.olympus-imaging.com/sdkdocs/data/PropertyList/property_list.html#property_28)の座標範囲内なのでしょうか？

もしかしましたら、`exec_takemotion.cgi?com=newstarttake`としていすると撮影できるかもしれません。

Comment: ライブビュー転送開始後、コマンド実行すれば撮影することができました。
ありがとうございます。